# POST request in ruby - from python

Tags: ruby, post, net-http

I need to send some POST data through a ruby script. I've been able to send it through python, using `requests`, with the following code:

```
payload = {"firstName": "John", "lastName": "Appleseed"}
headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
r = requests.post ("http://localhost:8000/api/v1/person/?format=json",data=json.dumps(payload), headers = headers)
```

Now, I tried to translate it into ruby with `net/http`:

```
url = "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/person/?format=json"
payload = {:firstName => 'John', :lastName => 'Appleseed'}.to_s

request = Net::HTTP::Post.new(url)
request.add_field('content-type', 'application/json')
request.body = payload

uri = URI.parse(url)
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
response = http.request(request)
```

But I'm getting 404 from the server. Any idea what I might be doing wrong with the ruby code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at what `payload` looks like:

```
>> {:firstName => 'John', :lastName => 'Appleseed'}.to_s
=> "firstNameJohnlastNameAppleseed"
```

`json.dumps` doesn't produce that output. You want to use `to_json` instead:

```
>> require "json"
=> true
>> {:firstName => 'John', :lastName => 'Appleseed'}.to_json
=> "{\"firstName\":\"John\",\"lastName\":\"Appleseed\"}"
```

Comment: I also had to change `url = "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/person/?format=json"` to `url = "http://localhost:8000` and  then create the request with a relative path: `request = Net::HTTP::Post.new("/api/v1/person/?format=json")`

Comment: Note you can use this syntax: `payload = {firstName: "John", lastName: "Appleseed"}` to create the hash.